# Paypal get transaction details with pay key using php curl

Tags: php, curl, paypal, payment, paykey

I get response after successful android paypal payment. The response was below.

```
{
    "response": {
       "state": "approved",
       "id": "PAY-6PU626847B294842SKPEWXHY",
 "create_time": "2014-07-18T18:46:55Z",
        "intent": "sale"
     },
   "client": {
       "platform": "Android",
       "paypal_sdk_version": "2.11.0",
         "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
        "environment": "mock"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
 }
 {
   "short_description": "Pay List Payment",
   "amount": "100",
    "intent": "sale",
    "currency_code": "USD"
 }
```

then I use the `PAY-6PU626847B294842SKPEWXHY` pay key and get the transaction details using PHP curl GET request with the following code.

```
$accessToken='<Access Token>';
$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6PU626847B294842SKPEWXHY");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($response);
exit;
```

After hit this i get the following response not get the transaction detail.

`{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"ddc1e3a55f10e"}`

anybody have idea thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you get after this above issue? Have you got any solution or not? I also stuck at the same response.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

**1. MAKE CURL POST TO GET ACCESS TOKEN**

```
$uri = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
    //for live production use $uri = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';

$clientId = '<YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE>';
$secret = '<YOUR-SECRET-HERE>';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 6); //NEW ADDITION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$access_token = '';
if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    $access_token = $json->access_token;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

**2. MAKE CURL POST TO GET TRANSACTION DETAILS LIKE payment status,amount, date etc.**

```
$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/<YOUR-PAYMENT-ID-HERE>";
$accessToken=$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($response);
exit;
```

**3. MAKE CURL POST TO GET MORE TRANSACTION DETAILS (This give more detailed response than step 2. so you can us this instead of step 2**

```
$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<YOUR-order-ID-HERE>";
$accessToken=$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($response);
exit;
```